# Idea project or ideas project

Tags: grammatical-number

I've got three types of projects: idea, evaluation and recruiter.

To refer to these projects, should I use "idea project" or "ideas project".

Same question for the other types: Is it "evaluation project" oder "evaluations project"? Is it "recruiter project" oder "recruiters project"?

An idea(s) projects is a project to gather ideas. Similarly an evaluation(s) project is a project to evaluate gathered ideas. A recruiter(s) project, is a project to recruit people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the lack of context it's difficult to tell what you're going for, so I'll try to explain what's going on here.

Basically, you have two choices. If your project is called "Idea", then the full phrase would be:

> The Idea project

Which implies a project called Idea, whatever the project is about. It might be one idea, or there may be more.

The same goes for any other names, examples:

> The Red Cross project, The Hidden Alpha project

Notice how the names are usually capitalized, as it's the project name.

The other choice would be:

> Ideas project / evaluations project / recruiters project

In this case, the first word is given much less emphasis, it stands as a simple "descriptor" of a project, not like a unique name of it. I'd say this is less professional, but again, it depends on the context you want to use this in.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the context, I'd say that *evaluation* and *recruiter* could be singular, but that *idea* should be plural: you don't want to give the impression that you have only one idea.

Comment: An idea(s) projects is a project to gather ideas. Similarly an evaluation(s) project is a project to evaluate gathered ideas. A recruiter project, is a project to recruit people.